When is $L(H)$ finite?
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $L(H)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $H$. I wondered if the following is true: $L(H)$ is a finite $W^*$-algebra if and only if $H$ is finite dimensional.
It is clear to me that $L(H)$ is a $W^*$-algebra of type I but I am quite puzzled about the finiteness. I also tried to find some references on the finiteness of $L(H)$ but I was not sucessful? Is this question difficult in general? I really did not get anywhere just by using the definitions somehow.

When you say $L(H)$ finite, do you mean finite dimensional or finite cardinality?

@Keen-ameteur No finiteness in terms of $W^*$-algebras. Both other notions would yield a completely basal question.

Yes, $L(H)$ is a finite von Neumann algebra if and only if $H$ is finite-dimensional. If $H$ is infinite-dimensional, let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal set and define $s e_n=e_{n+1}$ and $s|_{\{e_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}^\perp}=1_{\{e_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}^\perp}$. Then $s^\ast s=1_H$ and $ss^\ast=1-p$, where $p$ is the projection on the linear span of $e_1$. Thus $1-p\sim 1$, which means that $1$ is an infinite projection.
If $H$ is finite-dimensional, then $p\sim q$ if and only if $\mathrm{tr}(p)=\mathrm{tr}(q)$. In particular, $p\sim 1$ if and only if $\mathrm{tr}(p)=\operatorname{dim}H$, which is only the case for $p=1$. Thus $1$ is a finite projection.
